# Laravel redirecto to rout with parameters is not working as I wish

Tags: laravel, redirect, routes

I have a method controller with a parameter. Anytime I need to use it is working perfectly but now, I want to redirect back to that route after save a PDF and I'm getting this error "**Missing argument 1 for OrdersController::getJoiner()**".

This is the method...

```
public function getJoiner($id) {
   // some code
}
```

The controller name OrdersController and the route for getJoiner($id) is 'orders.joiner'.

I repeat, everything is working fine when I need to use the method from other place but not when I want redirect to it.

I tried like this:

```
return Redirect::action('OrdersController@getJoiner', array($orderID));
return Redirect::to('orders/joiner/'. $orderID);
return Redirect::route('orders.joiner', [$orderID]);
return View::make('orders.joiner', $orderID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont show how you are redirecting, but your method needs a parameter so you have to make sure you're passing that id along with your redirect.

Something like this. This assumes you have the id that you want getjoiner() to use available where you're saving the PDF.

```
return redirect()->route('orders.joiner', $id);
```

Comment: It is not working man, I share many ways I used to redirect but no one is working.